# DataGridView only shows rows up to the end of the window

Tags: c#, datagridview

So, I have a DataGridView that I load during the execution of my program.
I set the columns of the grid through this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vet.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column" + i, vet[i]);
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            }
```

And I add each row manually through this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < atributtes.Count; i++)
            {
                vet = new string[atributtes[0].Count];
                for (int j = 0; j < vet.Length; j++)
                    vet[j] = atributtes[i][j].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(vet);
            }
```

I'm reading this `vet` array from a text file. ScrollBars are set in the form properties, I've double checked.

The problem here is that this code does work, it fills the grid, but only to the end point of it in the window. The rows that would be added after that point do not show and the scrollbar does not show me them.
To be more accurate, it shows exactly one row pass that point as such:

[image: DataGridView not collaborating with me]

The loading loop does every 827 loops and each time it hits the `Rows.Add()` flawlesly, but only about 20 lines show up in the end product.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the value of your `atributtes.Count` ? Your code snippet seems to be just ok. I suggest you to check your data. I know that this is suppose to be a but I am not able to post a comment so I post an answer.

I hope that I help you.

**EDIT:**

I think I found what is wrong in your code. Can you try to remove this line

dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

I think there is a conplict in your autosize mode and you scroll bar.
I hope that I help you.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. That line there is just to ajust the columns to the grid size. The `atritubuttes.Count` is 827, acoording to debugging.
Another thing, this doesn't mess up my code's functionality, it's just for appearance's sake.